# Why do bubble rings stop rising near the surface, and then spontaneously dissipate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

When I've blown bubble rings in my pool I've noticed that every single time a ring rises to the surface it stops rising about 1-2 centimeters from the surface, stopping in place. Then, it spontaneously breaks into many tiny bubbles which then surface. It happens no matter how perfect my rings are or how still the water is. Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

Comment: Possibly something to do with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_(aerodynamics), with the surface of water acting as the "ground"?

Comment: Care to post a video?

Comment: @Deep this one is perfect - https://youtu.be/GbmTFa-h8Ts

Comment: See this [article](http://www.math.unm.edu/~nitsche/pubs/2006EMP.pdf), section 3.3 (page 8-10). Does it answer your question?